# UIActivityViewController Gmail sharing option the subject and body is set twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` for showing sharing option. Everything working except when user selects the Gmail sharing option.
In the list when I select Gmail the subject and body is set **twice**.

```
NSString *socialUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@",videoId];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:socialUrl];
        NSString *strText = @"Shared via TopCod";
        NSString *url1 = @"http://www.topcod.tv/";

        NSArray *ary =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:url,strText,url1,nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:ary applicationActivities:nil];
    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                    UIActivityTypeMessage,
                                    UIActivityTypeMail,
                                    UIActivityTypePrint,
                                    UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                    UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                    UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                    UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                    ];
    [activityViewController setValue:strText forKey:@"subject"];
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get your work done. Here instead of using two seperate string you can use a single string and use `\n` delimiter to add new line.

```
NSString *socialUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@",videoId];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:socialUrl];
        NSString *strText = @"Shared via TopCod\n\nhttp://www.topcod.tv/";


        NSArray *ary =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:url,strText,nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:ary applicationActivities:nil];
    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                    UIActivityTypeMessage,
                                    UIActivityTypeMail,
                                    UIActivityTypePrint,
                                    UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                    UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                    UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                    UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                    UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                    ];
    [activityViewController setValue:strText forKey:@"subject"];
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, its possible pass by parameter the Recipient like "setToRecipients"?

Comment: It does not help boss. I tries your code but when i work with Gmail it does not work